# Collision in canvas and javascript for a game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

I have a problem with the collisions in my game.
If I shoot enemies, I can kill them. But when they shoot me, nothing happens. The collision algorithm doesn't work in that way, only works if two shots hit the payer... I don't know why... Here's the important part of the problem. Thank you so much! :

```
    var enemiesShotsArray=new Array(5);
var enemiesShotStartValues={
    //propieties of the enemiesShoots
    posX: 10,
    posY:  0, //300 es la normal para un rectangulo
    width: 5,
    height:5,
    speed: 0.08
}
var baseCanonJson={
    //propieties of the player
    posX: 360,
    posY: 348,
    width: 100,
    height: 80
}
for(var i=0;i<enemiesShotsArray.length;i++){
    if(i==0){
        enemiesShotsArray[i] = enemiesShotStartValues;
    } else if (i==1) {
        enemiesShotsArray[i] = enemiesShotStartValues;    
    } else if (i==2){
        enemiesShotsArray[i] = enemiesShotStartValues;
    } else if (i==3){
        enemiesShotsArray[i] = enemiesShotStartValues;
    } else if (i==4){
        enemiesShotsArray[i] = enemiesShotStartValues;
    }
}
function enemiesShoots(){
    ctx.fillStyle='white';
    for(var i=0;i<enemies.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<enemiesShotsArray.length;j++){
            enemiesShotsArray[j].posX=enemies[i].posX;
            ctx.fillRect(enemiesShotsArray[j].posX+20,enemiesShotsArray[j].posY+20,10,10);
            enemiesShotsArray[j].posY+=enemiesShotsArray[j].speed;
            if(enemiesShotsArray[j].posY>canvas.height){
                enemiesShotsArray[j].posY=0;
            } else if(enemies.length<=3){
                enemiesShotsArray[j].posY+=0.1;
            }
        }
    }
}

function playerCollision(){ //COLLISION WHEN THE ENEMIES SHOOT TO THE PLAYER
    for(var j=0;j<enemiesShotsArray.length;j++){
        if(collisions(enemiesShotsArray[j],baseCanonJson)){ //if this is true, the code that will run is
            lives--;
            playerDamage();
            alert(lives);
        } else { console.log("nothing happen"); }
    }
}
    function collisions(d,e){ //algorithm of collision
    if (d.posX < e.posX + e.width  && d.posX + d.width  > e.posX &&
        d.posY < e.posY + e.height && d.posY + d.height > e.posY){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `for(var i=0;i<enemiesShotsArray.length;i++)` appears to be doing the same thing five times. Won't solve the issue, but surely you can remove the conditionals entirely, as you only have five elements in the array.

Comment: thank u for uu reply my friend. I already delete that line of code, but I still can not have the result that I want,which is that: the enemies shot (just one, like the first one of the enemiesShotsArray) hit me so i can start dying. Thank u for your time bro!

Comment: your collisions(d,e) could be made clearer to read. What does the (d, e) stand for? And you will want to use an else { return false; }. Third, try to use () for each equation in there. Something like: ((d.posX < e.posX + e.width) && (d.posX + d.width  > e.posX), that will help to make sure things happen as you want them.